# Linq nested select query and result has same structure with selected items

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I stucked to write a nested query with Select or SelectMany.

Let's take the traditional nested list that:

```
Sheet has Title fields
SheetDetail has Employee fields
```

Each Sheet has multiple SheetDetails as a master-detail manner.

I would like to make the result as below.

From below data...

```
Sheet   - SheetDetail
"A Sheet"-{"jane","herry","tom"}
"B Sheet"-{"kane","brown","jane"}
"C Sheet"-{"annie","ralph"}
```

To the result as below that has only 'jane' but **maintain same master-detail structure.**

```
Sheet   - SheetDetail
"A Sheet"-{"jane"}
"B Sheet"-{"jane"}
```

I tried

```
sheet.SelectMany(s => s.SheetDetails.Where(d => d.Description.Contains("jane")));
```

but as we can imagine, it gives wrong result.

How can I make it? please help-

Comment: `SheetDetail has Employee fields` which is a string?

Comment: {"jane","herry","tom"} is description of one record or 3 records? you need to clarify more your question

Comment: @IlyaIvanov // yes, just a string for simplicity in here.

Comment: @CuongLe // thanks for your attention. yes three records like List<string>

Comment: Could you define your classes and the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Any` to check:

```
Sheet.Where(s => s.SheetDetails.Any(d => d.Description == "jane")))
    .Select(s => new Sheet {
            Description = s.Description,
            SheetDetails = s.SheetDetails.Where(d => d.Description == "jane")
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have exactly one SheetDetail in result, you can create anonymous object like:

```
sheet
  .Where(s => s.SheetDetails.Any(d => d == "jane"))
  .Select(s => new {Sheet = s, SheetDetail == s.SheetDetails.First(d => d == "jane")});
```

Comment: Even I couldn't select yours as an answer, but I upvote yours. thanks for your kindness.